# Webpack not loading css

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, postcss

This is my first time trying to set up Webpack, so I'm sure I'm missing something here.

I am trying to load my PostCSS files with Webpack, using the ExtractTextPlugin to generate a css file into "dist". The problem is Webpack does not seem to pick up the css files. They are under "client/styles", but I've tried moving them to "shared", with the same result.

I ran Webpack with the --display-modules option, and verified that no css files display there.

I have tried running it without the extract text plugin, and the result is the same: no CSS is built into bundle.js.

Here is my prod config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './client'
  ],
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'shared'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:    /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel']
      },

      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader!postcss-loader'
        ),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],
  postcss: (webpack) => [
    require('postcss-import')({ addDependencyTo: webpack, path: ['node_modules', 'client'] }),
    require('postcss-url')(),
    require('precss')(),
    require('postcss-fontpath')(),
    require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: [ 'last 2 versions' ] })
  ]
};
```

And here's an example of my main css file:
    @import 'normalize.css/normalize';

```
/* Variables */
@import 'variables/colours';

/* Mixins */

/* App */

/* Components */

body {
  background-color: $black;
}
```

Would anyone have an idea on why this is happening? Am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you are using style-loader and css-loader. You can include css in the js file itself. You can just `require(style.css)` or `import 'style.css'` (if using ES6) in the javascript file which is using the styles. No need to provide an entry point to **webpack** for css.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. :) In my case, I'm dealing with an isomorphic application, so I need the styles to load before the JS, or else there will be a FOUC. However, will keep that in mind for other situations.

Comment: Then use have a look at `isomorphic style loader`, it solves the FOUC issue. It is an extension of style loader for isomorphic apps.

Answer (score 53):

So, after three hours of hitting my head against the wall, I finally got it. I hope this will help someone in the future.

All I needed to do was to add `'./client/styles/main.css'` to the entry points. Yey.

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had `"sideEffects": false` in my package.json, which caused webpack not to emit CSS.

Comment: Thanks @frodo2975! In my case there were specific files in `sideEffects` (```"sideEffects": [ fileA.js, fileB.js]```) which also blocked the specific file I was trying to load.

Comment: This was indeed helpful i was trying to figure why it is not working

Answer (score 4):

Not directly related to the OP's problem, but here was my problem (my CSS wasn't loading either).

Personally, I was missing the `style-loader` package: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#hmr-with-stylesheets

Comment: Right, in my case I just forgot to update both style-loader and css-loader after upgrading to webpack 5

Comment: Thanks, had the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related with *react-hot-loader*. I was using webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() and after deleting it CSS in my editor started working.

Comment: Just to make this info useful: what you're saying is that react-hot-loader handles hot module replacement, so webpack's plugin can be removed? thx