# webpack server doesn't load css stylesheet

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am writing a webpage with ReactJS.
I made a css stylesheet to change some bootstrap classes (for my Navbar fonts), added the link to html file, and it did not work. Then I installed style loaders and edited webpack.config file, but again server can't load css file. See below my webpack.config code .

```
var path = require("path");

var webpack = require('webpack');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");

var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css?/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
                include: SRC_DIR
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Status Code for the css file is 404 not found, nothing else.

Comment: This is a total shot in the dark, but have you tried to add the css path to the entry section? Check out this post and the answer with 10 upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963051/webpack-not-loading-css

Comment: what do you mean by "added the link to html file" ? This is not what webpack is meant to. The style-loader will only turn your css into js. You need a plugin to turn it into a "real" css.

Comment: if the css style sheet is loaded in your index.html via a `<link/>`, then you don't even need a loader. You would need a loader if you imported your css into your react components. If you're getting a 404 in the browser, then the path to the style sheet is incorrect.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Thanks very much, I fixed it.

Comment: @Suzy Melkonyan You're very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a link such as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/some/path/styles.css">` in your html file does not require a loader in `webpack.config.js`.

It sounds like you're getting a console error in the browser that says 404 file not found.

If that i the case then the `href="/some/path/styles.css"` part is not pointing to your file.

Furthermore, I assume, ( I know, dangerous... ) that you are trying to serve your css file from a `public` folder, and that your server possibly has this folder set as a static asset folder. If that is the case, you do not need to include that folder name in the path you used in the `href` of your `link`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is explicitly require CSS or Sass dependencies like you would its JS dependencies, and Webpack will build a bundle that includes everything you need. For Example

src/app/index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; //bootstrap installed via npm
import '../css/custom.css'; // just an example path
```

For more detail explanation [Webpack Embedded Stylesheets](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html)